# Перегрузить метод объекта или изменить private свойство родителя

Tags: php, доступ

Есть класс зашифрованный ioncube (назовём класс А). При его использовании наследовался этот класс (класс В), переопределяя публичный метод. Сейчас изменились исходные данные и нужно изменить приватное свойство класса А. Чтобы изменить приватное свойство объекта нашёл https://3v4l.org/nCMor (описание https://habrahabr.ru/post/186718/), но как добраться в таком случае к приватному свойству родительского класса?
Если использую напрямую класс А, свойство обновляется без проблем (используя метод выше), но как в созданном экземпляре перегрузить нужный метод? Смотрел рефлексию, но не понял как это сделать.
Пример:

```
<?php
class A { //зашифрованный
  private $field = array('field1', 'field2');
  public function getNameTable(){
     return 'Table1';
  }
  /*...... разные методы ......*/
}
class B extends A{
      public function getNameTable(){
         return 'Table2';
      }
}
```

Необходимо добавить в массив $field ещё 1 элемент 'field3' но при этом должна использоваться таблица 'Table2'

Р.S.Связывался с разработчиком класса А, он сказал, что больше этим не занимается и исходников у него уже нет.

Comment: то есть вам кроме значения поля нужно подменить метод в самом *базовом классе*?

Comment: @Alex, класс расшифруйте и меняйте что душе угодно в нем.

Comment: @Visman, а какой программой лучше это сделать? (расшифровку) я делал IonCube v8.3 Decoder, но большинство названия переменных отобразились абракатаброй.... остальное нормально. пробовал подбирать кодировку - не получилось....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример с `Reflection` для модификации `private` поля родительского класса

```
<?php
class A
{
    private $data = array('one', 'two');
    public function __construct() { }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->patchWithReflect($this, 'data', $value);
    }

    public function patchWithReflect($object, $name, $value)
    {
        // Получаем информацию о родительском классе
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(get_parent_class($object));
        // Получаем доступ к свойству
        $data = $reflect->getProperty($name);
        $data->setAccessible(true);
        // Получаем старое значение
        $dataA = $data->getValue($object);
        // Устанавливаем новое
        $dataA[] = $value;
        $data->setValue($object, $dataA);
    }

}

$bz = new B('z');
$bx = new B('x');
var_dump($bx);
var_dump($bz);
```

[результат на ideone](http://ideone.com/PvW0FF)